# show hide not working with tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a search function with tabbed feature. It is showing currently fine. No error at all.
Problem is when i want to click on any tab it need to show/hide some of the content of other tab.
  Whenever i click on any div it is showing the div content but not hiding or showing anything.

```
 <div id="newsearchs" class="row">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <ul id="myTab" class="nav# nav-tabs test">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#" id="pep">People</a>

                    </li>

                <li><a href="#" name = "job" id="job">Jobs</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#" id="loca" name = "loca">Location</a>

                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="input-group input-group-md">
            <input type="text" id= "search_value" class="form-control " placeholder="Search for ...">
            <input name="search_location" id="search_location" placeholder="Location" class="form-control txt-auto"/>

            <div id="people" class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Looking For <span class="caret"></span>

                </button>
                <ul class="navbar-custom-menu dropdown-menu pull-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Student</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Teacher</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Institue</a>

                    </li>
                 </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="jobs" class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Brief format <span class="caret"></span>

                </button>
                <ul class="navbar-custom-menu dropdown-menu pull-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Brief format</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Detailed format</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Citesummary</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">LaTeX (EU)</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="locations" class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Brief format <span class="caret"></span>

                </button>
                <ul class="navbar-custom-menu dropdown-menu pull-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Brief format</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Detailed format</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Citesummary</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">LaTeX (EU)</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /btn-group --> <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>

            </button>
            </span>
        </div>
```

Here are the jquery code which not working at the moment.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#jobs').hide();
$('#locations').hide();
$('#search_location').hide();

$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!($(this).attr('id') == 'pep')) {
         $('#search_location').hide();
        $('#search_value').show();
        $('#people').show();
        $('#jobs').hide();
        $('#locations').hide();
    }
    $(this).tab('show');
})
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#myTab b').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!($(this).attr('id') == 'job')) {
         $('#search_location').hide();
        $('#search_value').show();
        $('#jobs').show();
        $('#people').hide();
        $('#locations').hide();
    }
    $(this).tab('show');
})
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#myTab c').click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    if (!($(this).attr('id') == 'loca')) {
         alert('Hi');
        $('#search_location').show();
        $('#search_value').hide();
        $('#locations').show();
        $('#jobs').hide();
        $('#people').hide();
  //  }
    $(this).tab('show');

})
</script>
```

According to me     `$('#myTab c').click(function (e) {` is not firing.
Please advise what am i doing wrong.

Comment: You must be joking right? there is not tag such as `<c href="">click</c>`

Comment: try with all click function `$('#myTab a')` is `a` target with `<a>`  tag  And `tab('show')` is not a defined function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of HTML and JS formatting issues.

1. you have commented out a closing `{` before the third tab show call, ie. `//  }`, you will need to uncomment this out
2. you are referring to html elements that dont exist. `#myTab b` and `#myTab c` are trying to look for html elements of tags `<b>` and `<c>`, but you're trying to attach handlers to the `<a>` tags, in which case, you can combine a lot of your code
3. your if statements appear to be looking for when the `id` is not equal to something, which would mean 2 lots of show/hide's would be getting triggered per tab change, these should be simplified to (ideally a switch statement) handle each tab's click event individually
4. you have a number of unclosed `<div>` tags, and a stray `#` in your class definition of your `myTab` element.

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/211w3rp6/)**

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $('#jobs').hide();
    $('#locations').hide();
    $('#search_location').hide();

    $('#myTab a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (($(this).attr('id') == 'pep')) {
            $('#search_location').hide();
            $('#search_value').show();
            $('#people').show();
            $('#jobs').hide();
            $('#locations').hide();
        }
        if (($(this).attr('id') == 'job')) {
            $('#search_location').hide();
            $('#search_value').show();
            $('#jobs').show();
            $('#people').hide();
            $('#locations').hide();
        }
        if (($(this).attr('id') == 'loca')) {
            $('#search_location').show();
            $('#search_value').hide();
            $('#locations').show();
            $('#jobs').hide();
            $('#people').hide();
        }
        $(this).tab('show');
    })
})
```